# How can I create (nested) Keynote.app slides from a XML file?

Tags: script, keynote, automation, xml

I have some nested lists (XML/OPML file) and I am looking for a (automated) process to create Keynote presentations from them. Use case: I write concepts for presentations in an [Outliner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outliner), then would like to transfer the structure directly to a Keynote presentation for further editing. The structure may be something like this:

```
Breakfast
    - Coffee
    - Muesli
        · Yoghurt
        · Milk
        · Cereal
    - Mango
Lunch
    - Pasta
    - Water
    - Small Salad
Dinner
    - Fries
    - Caesar Salad
```

While [OmniOutliner](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnioutliner/) *does* export to [Keynote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keynote_%28presentation_software%29), **all** nodes are flattened into bullet points on the top-level slides. Using the data above, it would only create three slides.

However, I would prefer the following: Every list item creates a separate slide, with all slides nested according to the original structure. The process should be automated, and the styling in Keynote is not of concern. NB: Nested slides are possible in Keynote:

[image: Nested Slides in Keynote]

Any ideas including Applescript, Automator or the Terminal (command line), are welcome.

Comment: It looks like someone voted to close this question. Is it possible that this question would be better suited for Stack Overflow? Maybe it could be edited so that it is more clear that you want to use an Apple Script or Terminal to achieve this? Obviously programming questions are off-topic but AppleScript and Automator questions are perfectly fine.

Comment: @bassplayer7 Thanks for the tip! I have edited the question. I thought about posting to SO, but did not because I do appreciate the community here and think the question is more a Mac question than a programming question -- after all, it’s about OmniGraffle and Keynote.app

Comment: Your edit looks really good. Hopefully someone will have a great answer for you.